# Numpy: broadcasting + boolean indexing

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have the following numpy arrays

```
A: shape (n1, n2) array of float
B: shape (n2,) array of float
M: shape (n1, n2) array of bool
```

How do I turn the following pseduo-code inte *efficient* real code? The arrays may be huge, possibly > 100 million elements.

```
A[M] = ("B broadcast to shape (n1,n2)")[M]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Broadcasting is simple and memory efficient:

```
A, B, M = np.broadcast_arrays(A, B, M)
```

However using this `B` in your code `A[M] = B[M]` would not be memory efficient because `B[M]` has as many real elements as `M` has `True` values.

Instead use:

```
np.putmask(A, M, B)
```

Since `B` is repeated automatically with the `putmask` function, you should not even have to broadcast it. Though I guess it cannot hurt to do that.